# Guessing a word from random triplet alphabets

Tags: java, c++, string, algorithm, data-structures

I came across this problem that I can't figure out its full solution yet.
(source: http://www.careercup.com/question?id=5678056593162240)

> Given a function
>
> getRandomTripplet()
>
> which returns a random triplet of letters from a string. You don't
>   know the string using calls to this function you have to correctly
>   guess the string. the length of the string is also given.
>
> Lets say the string is helloworld the function getRandomTriplet will
>   return things like
>
> hlo  hew  wld  owo
>
> the function maintains the relative order of the letters. so it will
>   never return
>
> ohl since h is before o in the string.  owe since w is after e
>
> The string is not known you are only given length of the string.

My approach so far is running the getRandomTripplet() 1000 times, then look up duplicate characters by getting the ones with highest occurrences (probability > 1/10).

Am I on the right track?

Thanks for your help.
Cheers!

Comment: Are you using Java or C++?

Comment: Both would do, but I prefer Java

Answer (score 1):

After failing to produce a probabilistic solution, I came up with this brute-force approach that seems to produce correct results. For some strings, the total state space is quite big, but the algorithm will converge eventually :)

It is probably not the most efficient solution, but it does seem to do the trick. The code below can be optimized quite a bit, but as an example it should be sufficient.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <functional>

#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp>

// the input string for the random generator
static const std::string input("hello_world");
// an "empty" character (something not present in the input string)
static const char empty = '?';
// a constant with the input length (the only known fact about the input in the algorithm)
static const unsigned length = input.length();

// randomization algorithm returning triplets
std::string randomTriplet() {
    static boost::random::mt19937 gen;
    static boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, input.length()-1);

    std::set<unsigned> indices;
    while(indices.size() < 3)
        indices.insert(dist(gen));

    std::string result;
    for(auto i : indices)
        result.push_back(input[i]);
    return result;
}

// runs a functor for all possible combinations of input triplet acc to the rules
void allCombinations(const std::string& triplet, const std::function<void(const std::string&)>& functor) {
    for(unsigned a=0;a<length-2;++a)
        for(unsigned b=a+1;b<length-1;++b)
            for(unsigned c=b+1;c<length;++c) {
                std::string tmp(length, empty);
                tmp[a] = triplet[0];
                tmp[b] = triplet[1];
                tmp[c] = triplet[2];

                functor(tmp);
            }
}

// tries to merge two strings, and returns an empty string if it is not possible
std::string putTogether(const std::string& first, const std::string& second) {
    std::string result(length, empty);

    for(unsigned a=0;a<length;++a)
        if((first[a] == empty) || (first[a] == second[a]))
            result[a] = second[a];
        else if(second[a] == empty)
            result[a] = first[a];
        else if(first[a] != second[a])
            return std::string();

    return result;
}

// run a single iteration on a set of input states and a triplet
std::set<std::string> iterate(const std::set<std::string>& states, const std::string& triplet) {
    std::set<std::string> result;

    // try all combinations on all states
    for(auto& s : states) {
        allCombinations(triplet, [&](const std::string& val) {
            // and if merge is possible, insert it into the result
            const std::string together = putTogether(s, val);
            if(!together.empty())
                result.insert(together);
        });
    };

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
    // the current state space (all possible strings given the observations so far)
    std::set<std::string> states;

    // initialisation - take the first triplet and generate all combinations of this triplet
    allCombinations(randomTriplet(), [&](const std::string& val) { states.insert(val); });

    // iterate - the number of iterations is rather arbitrary. We cannot stop when the solution
    //   count is 1, because some input strings (like "hello world", where the double l and o 
    //   are the problem) don't have a unique solution
    for(unsigned a=0;a<10000;++a) {
        states = iterate(states, randomTriplet());
        std::cout << "\r" << "iteration #" << a << ", combinations count = " << states.size() << "   " << std::flush;

        // however, if we do find a single solution, we don't have to go on
        if(states.size() == 1)
            break;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // print them all
    for(const auto& i : states)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Interestingly enough, for "hello_world" input, the output is:

```
iteration #9999, combinations count = 6     
hello_world
helol_world
hlelo_world
hleol_world
lhelo_world
lheol_world
```

The triple 'l' and double 'o' characters produce an ambiguity that cannot be decided only using the observation method with three characters.